# How to make AI follow the sprite, when the sprite is within a certain distance of AI

Tags: c#, xna

The aim i'm trying achieve here, is when the whiteball (sprite), goes towards the blackball (AI) within a certain distance, the blackball will then follow whiteball.

I have made it so the AI automatically goes towards the sprite, but I don't have a idea of how to do when only the sprite is within a certain distance.

### Main Game class

This is the main game class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.IO;

namespace PickUpTheCrewGame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class PickUpTheCrewGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SpriteFont messageFont;
        Texture2D backgroundTexture;
        Rectangle backgroundRectangle;
        Sprite BlueBall;
        Sprite GreenBall;
        Sprite OrangeBall;
        Sprite PinkBall;
        Sprite RedBall;
        Sprite c;
        Sprite YellowBall;

        //---player scores
        int playerScore = 0;


        //List<Sprite> sprite = new List<Sprite>();
        List<sharks> sharks = new List<sharks>();
        List<Sprite> crew = new List<Sprite>();
        //Sprite Background;


        public PickUpTheCrewGame()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            //sreen size
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            //enable the mousepointer
            IsMouseVisible = true;
            base.Initialize();
        }

        public void Save(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextWriter textOut = null;
            try
            {
                textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);
                Save(textOut);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (textOut != null) textOut.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Save(TextWriter textOut)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.Y);

                }

                foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine("Shark");
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.Y);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        public void Load(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextReader textIn = null;
            //try
            //{
                textIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
                Load(textIn);
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
            //    throw e;
            //}
            //finally
            //{
                if (textIn != null) textIn.Close();
            //}
        }

        private void Load(TextReader textIn)
        {
            foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
            {

                crew1.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                crew1.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());

            }
            foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
            {
               enemySprite.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                enemySprite.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());

            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            backgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
            backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle(
             0, 0, // top left hand corner
             Window.ClientBounds.Width,
             Window.ClientBounds.Height); // size of screen display



            //-------Captains crew-------

            c = new Sprite(new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0),
                  Content.Load<Texture2D>("WhiteBall"), Color.White);

            BlueBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(640, 450),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueBall"));
            crew.Add(BlueBall);

            GreenBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(250, 600),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("GreenBall"));
            crew.Add(GreenBall);

            OrangeBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(115, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("OrangeBall"));
            crew.Add(OrangeBall);

            RedBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(500, 600),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("RedBall"));
            crew.Add(RedBall);

            YellowBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(800, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("YellowBall"));
            crew.Add(YellowBall);

            PinkBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(25, 175),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("PinkBall"));
            crew.Add(PinkBall);

            //--------Sharks------
            sharks s = new sharks(new Vector2(1000, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(900, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(800, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);



            messageFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("messageFont");


            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to `enter code here`unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            //----------This gets the time value---------
            float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            //--------------keyboard input---------------
            //Exit
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                this.Exit();
            //Save
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                Save("test.txt");
            //Load
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.L))
                Load("test.txt");

            //Directional Movement
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                c.velocity.X = -350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                c.velocity.X = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                c.velocity.Y = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                c.velocity.Y = -350;

            c.Update(elapsed);
            foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
            {
                cr.Update(elapsed);
            }


            c.col = Color.White;

            //----sharks intersects with whiteball----
            foreach (sharks s in sharks)
            {
                if (c.bounds.Intersects(s.bounds))
                {
                    c.col = Color.Red;
                    break;
                }
            }

            foreach (sharks s in sharks)
            {
                s.Update(elapsed, c.location);
            }

            //----sprites intersect with whiteball----
            foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
            {
                if (c.bounds.Intersects(crew1.bounds))
                {
                    c.col = Color.Red;
                    playerScore += 1;
                    crew1.bounds.X = 10000;
                    crew1.bounds.Y = 10000;
                    crew1.location.Y = 10000;
                    crew1.location.X = 10000;
                    break;
                }

            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, backgroundRectangle,
 Color.White);


            //Background.Draw(spriteBatch);
            c.Draw(spriteBatch);
            foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
            {
                cr.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }


            foreach (sharks s in sharks)
            {
                s.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            //---------messsage font succussfully saved----------

            spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, playerScore.ToString(),
                new Vector2(145, 0),
                Color.White);

            spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, " Player Scores",
                new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);


            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

### Sprite class

Sprite class holds the movements, boundaries everything

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace PickUpTheCrewGame
{
    class Sprite
    {
        public Vector2 location;
        public Vector2 velocity;//this hold the sprite movement
        public Texture2D image;
        public Rectangle bounds;//inventing the boundaries using rectange variable
        public Color col = Color.White;
        int maxVel = 600;


        public Sprite(Vector2 location, Texture2D image, Color clr)
        {
            this.location = location;
            this.image = image;
            this.col = clr;
            //----setting the boundaries of the screen to match the window-----
            bounds = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, 64, 64);

        }
        public Sprite(Vector2 location, Texture2D image)
        {
            this.location = location;
            this.image = image;

            //----setting the boundaries of the screen to match the window-----
            bounds = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, 64, 64);

        }

        public Sprite(Vector2 location,Vector2 vel, Texture2D image, Color clr)
        {
            this.location = location;
            this.velocity = vel;
            this.image = image;
            this.col = clr;
            //----setting the boundaries of the screen to match the window-----
            bounds = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, 64, 64);

        }
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(image, location, col);
        }

        public void Update(float elapsed)
        {
            //----sets the speed for the players----
            location += velocity * elapsed;



            //-------initialising the boundaries for the screen-----
            bounds.X = (int)location.X;
            bounds.Y = (int)location.Y;

            //--------Posotive velocity---------
            if (velocity.X > maxVel)
                velocity.X = maxVel;

            if (velocity.Y > maxVel)
                velocity.Y = maxVel;

            //----Negative velocity-------
            if (velocity.X < -maxVel)
                velocity.X = -maxVel;

            if (velocity.Y < -maxVel)
                velocity.Y = -maxVel;

            //------adding friction to the AI------
            velocity = velocity * 0.9f;

            //-------Assigning the boundaries-----
            if (bounds.Left < 0)
                location.X = 0;

            if (bounds.Top < 0)
                location.Y = 0;

            if (bounds.Right > 1280)
                location.X = 1280 - bounds.Width;

            if (bounds.Bottom > 720)
                location.Y = 720 - bounds.Height;
        }
        public void Accelerate(Vector2 direction)
        {
            //-----normalises is to get a unit vector (40 is force), normal is direction
            velocity += 15 * Vector2.Normalize(direction);
        }

    }
}
```

### AI class

Simple enemy sprite(AI) class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;


namespace PickUpTheCrewGame
{
    class sharks:Sprite
    {
        public sharks(Vector2 location, Texture2D image)
            :base(location,image)
        {

        }
        public void Update(float elapsed, Vector2 playerLoc)
        {
            Accelerate(playerLoc - location);//should make the ai go towards the player all the time

            base.Update(elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Erm not sure, I thought my AI class was my AI, I have some of the set up in the Sprite class as well

Comment: My mistake.  I have updated your question to show individual listings.  I did not see your AI class at the end. :)

Comment: No worries, I have tried searching it up and trying but haven't gotten no luck, why I was hoping someone could potentially help me out also I'm quite new to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the distance between the white ball and the black ball by subtract their location vectors. This give you a vector that represent the "gap" between your two balls.

You already do it (when you call Accelerate) to get the direction. If you want the distance, just get the Lenght of that Vector2 obtained by subtraction : it's actually the distance between the 2 balls.

Put a condition on this distance (SharkVision in my example) and your sharks will move only if the distance is lower than SharkVision. Adjust SharkVision the obtain the result that suits you best.

```
class sharks:Sprite
{
    public const float SharkVision = 500f;
    ...
    public void Update(float elapsed, Vector2 playerLoc)
    {
        if ((playerLoc - location).Length() < SharkVision) 
            Accelerate(playerLoc - location);

        base.Update(elapsed);
    }
}
```

## Demo with a schema

[image: Scheme]

In this image, "a" is the vector of location of the white ball and "b" the one of the black ball.
If you substract them, you obtain the vector "a-b". Its length is equal to the distance that separate the two balls and its orientation gave you the direction of move.

Warning : the direction of the substraction can invert the direction of move. Always do : `destinationLocation - startLocation`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. After adding that to my code, I get an error message saying "Operator '<' cant be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'float'.

Comment: My bad : Length is a method. Add parenthesis. I fix my post.

Comment: How would go I about the parenthesis please. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: The sharks don't seem to awake within a certain distance at all, i've changed the float to a higher number but no difference, thank you

Comment: Put a higher value again. It's my mistake : 2.5 is really low in this case because it say that the player need to be at 2.5 pixels from the shark. Change it for 500. I fix my post again.